# Single page application client and server routing

Tags: express, routes, single-page-application, pushstate

I've got the following code to handle client side navigation using HTML5 pushstate (classic combination of crossroadsjs and historyjs):

```
History = window.History;
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', function () {
var state = History.getState();
console.log(state);
if (state.data.urlPath) {
    return crossroads.parse(state.data.urlPath); 
}
else
{
   if (state.hash.length > 1) {
      var fullHash = state.hash;
      var hashPath = fullHash.slice(0, fullHash.indexOf('?'));
      return crossroads.parse(hashPath);
   }
}});

crossroads.normalizeFn = crossroads.NORM_AS_OBJECT;
crossroads.parse('/');

$('body').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var title, urlPath;
    urlPath = $(this).attr('href');

    if (urlPath.slice(0, 1) == '#'){
         return true;
    }

    e.preventDefault();
    title = $(this).text().trim();

    return History.pushState({ urlPath: urlPath }, title, urlPath);
    });
```

It works really well. Now, to handle url bookmarking and sharing, I added and express server to handle all requests. All it does is to redirect to index.html (a sort of catchall rule):

```
var env = require('./env');
var fallback = require('express-history-api-fallback');
var express = require('express');

var app = express();
var config = env.config();
var root = __dirname + '/dist';

app.use(express.static(root));

app.use(fallback('index.html', { root: root }));

var port = process.env.PORT || 9090;

var server = app.listen(port, function () {
    console.log('Server started at: http://localhost:' + port);
    console.log(config);
});
```

The problem I am facing is that it successfully redirects to index.html but it doesn't load the correct route on the client side. So a request to ***www.mysite.com*** or ***www.mysite.com/anotherpage*** will always load the home page route.

I am obviously missing some code to intercept that and load the appropriate route on the client side. I just don't know what to do.

Comment: If you dont wan to take the hassle, there is a framework [slim](http://www.slimframework.com/) which will take all the routing maintanance.

Comment: Thanks but now way I'm adding a PHP framework to my stack. Nothing against it, don't get me wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Found where the bug was:

> crossroads.parse('/');

This was always redirecting to the "home" route. I just had to refactor the code a bit:

```
History.Adapter.bind(window, 'statechange', this.routeCrossRoads);

routeCrossRoads() {
    var state = History.getState();
    if (state.data.urlPath) {
        return crossroads.parse(state.data.urlPath);
    }
    else {
        if (state.hash.length > 1) {
            var fullHash = state.hash;
            var pos = fullHash.indexOf('?');

            if (pos > 0) {
                var hashPath = fullHash.slice(0, pos);
                return crossroads.parse(hashPath);
            }
            else {
                return crossroads.parse(fullHash);
            }
        }
        else {
            return crossroads.parse('/');
        }
    }
}
```